# How to limit the number of entries returned when using multiple matches in a Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets

Below is the structure of my Google Sheets document. I want to limit the number of results returned by the query, but on each match and not for the entire query.

Here is what my current formula look like

```
=query({Sheet5!A2:B}, " select * where Col1 matches 'School A|School B|School C' 
and Col2 is not null desc limit 5 ")
```

So what happens here is that the formula finds all the matches as requested by the formula and goes on to limit the number of total entries to 5. What I want is to limit the results to 5 per match so that School A results are 5, School B results are also 5 etc.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Proposed solution:

### Arrays

You can use [arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) which involves combining three separate queries into one formula.

For example:

```
={1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3}
```

Gives you this:

[image]

### Your example

You can do something similar for 3 separate queries, putting all queries between `{}` and separating them by a `;`:

```
={
query(Sheet1!A2:B, "SELECT * WHERE A MATCHES 'School A' AND B IS NOT NULL ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 5", 0);
query(Sheet1!A2:B, "SELECT * WHERE A MATCHES 'School B' AND B IS NOT NULL ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 5", 0);
query(Sheet1!A2:B, "SELECT * WHERE A MATCHES 'School C' AND B IS NOT NULL ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 5", 0)
}
```

Which will give you something like this:

[image]

---

It is possible in SQL to do a GROUP_CONCAT and make it into one single query, but AFAIK Google Sheets Query does not support that. This way seemed simpler anyway, unless you want to order globally by column B!

#### References

- [Google Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)